# How does datastore layout effect disk IO in a virtual environment?

Tags: virtualization, datastore

Having been working with virutal infrastructure, recently i have been facing some disk issues.

I am aware that my disks are not fast disk so i have made move to upgrade to fast disk, secondly, vms are distributed equally over the diff nodes (which generally is issue with disk), but here my concern is, does data-store affects disk IO or even CPU IO?

Note: apart from 2 vms, all are on same datastore.
it is also quite interesting that, same writes generating diff load and greater IO. (i.e. box1 took load average of 10, where as others took 20, 30, 40 respectively).

I am looking for some general feedback who has experience with Virtual infrastructure.

[image]

Comment: edited above in edit: section

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if the number of datastores have an effect or the protocol used to access them or the path you use the reach them through? *Any* of these can effect your VM's performance and in fact storage IO is almost always the first place a virtual environment hits a bottleneck. Some of the answers are also dependent on what you are using as your hypervisor.

Generally having more than one datastore is not going to improve performance, it used to be that block level disks could run into locking issues but with newer hypervisors this has been alleviated.

To answer your second questions, yes disk IO can (and often does) effect CPU performance. If a thread is waiting for information to be read from disk it holds up it's queue during that periond. On a Linux box this is called IO Wait (you can see it in *top*). On Windows it's called learn to use perfmon.

If you are having disk IO issues in a virtual environment the first place to look is # of disks, the second is how you've got them laid out (RAID level, # of spindles per stripe etc), the 3rd caching - how large is the read cache versus your IO trends (read/write heavy, sequential or random) and finally the pipe (1 gig Ethernet versus 10 or 2 gig FC versus 8 for instance).

It's rarely the pipe :)

Comment: TheFiddlerWins, got response to do further research on. Yes i meant by any kind of bottleneck due to having number of VMs in data-store.